# AWS s3api json formatting error: Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Not sure what I'm getting wrong with my json format. Just trying to test out aws cli and run `aws s3api list-objects --cli-input-json <json_file>.json --profile <profile_name>` where `<my_json>` is below but getting:

```
Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
JSON received: <my_json.json>

{"Bucket": "<bucket_name>","Delimiter": "","EncodingType": "","Marker": "","MaxKeys": 0,"Prefix": "<prefix_name>"}
```

Comment: `--cli-input-json file://my_json.json`

Comment: I'm using a linux server and the file is located in `/root/my_json.json`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer into string without using in-built function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477822/how-to-convert-an-integer-into-string-without-using-in-built-function)

Answer (score 59):

Instead of :

```
my_json.json
```

You have to use `file://` before the json name :

```
file://my_json.json
```

Comment: I'm running into this too, but I'm using file:// syntax.

Comment: Given the constraint above, I had to navigate to the exact folder on my local and then call `--cli-input-json` for AWS SES. Not sure why you can't just put a *nix path in there.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I think it was needing ASCII encoding (unicode being the default)... added `-Encoding ASCII -NoNewline` to my `Out-File` and it worked.

Comment: In particular I needed to generate my json file with via `aws {cmd} --generate-cli-skeleton | Out-File -encoding ascii aws-service.json` When I simply redirected the output to a file the cli would not accept that file.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only clue that works for me. I have to convert my json file to UTF-8 (with Notepad++). I am using AWS CLI v2.