# How to convert an integer into string without using in-built function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna ask how to convert an integer into string without using in-built function.

This is the original question:

Write a function `string(ls)` that returns a string representation of the list ls.

Note: do not use the built-in `str()` method for this task. We are attempting to emulate its behavior.

```
s = string(['a','b','c'])   # '['a','b','c']'

s = string([1,2,3])         # '[1, 2, 3]'

s = string([True])          # '[True]'

s = string([])              # '[]'
```

Restrictions: Don't just return `str(ls)`! Don't use the `str.join` method, don't use slicing.

Here is my code:

```
def string(ls):
    if len(ls)==0:
        mess="'[]'"
        return mess
    elif isinstance(ls[0],str):
        i=0
        mess="'["
        while True:
            if i==len(ls)-1:
                elem="'"+ls[i]+"'"
                mess=mess+elem
                break
            else:
                elem="'"+ls[i]+"', "
                mess=mess+elem
            i=i+1
        mess=mess+"]'"
        return mess
    else:
        i=0
        mess="'["
        while True:
            if i==len(ls)-1:
                elem=str(ls[i])+"]'"
                mess=mess+elem
                break
            else:
                elem=str(ls[i])+', '
                mess=mess+elem
            i=i+1
        return mess
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Sorry. I wanna ask how to convert an integer into string without using in-built function?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: You may do: `def String(List): return List.__str__()`. This is a bit of a hack, but it doesn’t use the `str` function, does it? ;)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I write my code using in-built function str(). But the question request me not use these kind of functions. Are there some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: No, the assignment says "Don't just return `str(ls)`", and you didn't do that. So what's the problem?

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry...I can't understand it completely. Can you explain a little bit specifically?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Oh...In the third line, it also requests me not use str() function

Comment: @AnYan, `str(a)` is almost the same as `a.__str__()` (look up “Python magic methods”). This doesn’t use `str`, so you may be fine. That’s probably not the way they want you to do it, though.

Comment: @ForceBru hhhh, yeah it is a tricky method. Thank you friend

Comment: how about:
```def string(ls):
  return repr(ls)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep dividing a given integer by 10 and prepending the remainder to the output string. Use the ordinal number of `'0'` plus the remainder to obtain the ordinal number of the remainder, and then convert it to string using the `chr` function:

```
def int_to_string(i):
    string = ''
    while True:
        i, remainder = divmod(i, 10)
        string = chr(ord('0') + remainder) + string
        if i == 0:
            break
    return string
```

so that:

```
print(int_to_string(0))
print(int_to_string(5))
print(int_to_string(65))
print(int_to_string(923))
```

would output:

```
0
5
65
923
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

This should work? I am fairly new so i do not know why your codes are so complicated.This should work too.

```
def int_to_string(i):
string = chr(ord("0") + i)
return string
```

Comment: The code which you provided is only work for single-digit integers, it is not working for numbers like 10 or 44