# How to use aws cli with cli-input-json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was having trouble using the cli-input-json by following the AWS documentation which seems simple enough ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-skeleton.html)), but was as per usual missing a key element that they assume everyone knows. That being that the JSON file needs to be UTF-8 encoded. By default when using Visual Studio Code & Powershell, it would get the skeleton file in UTF-16 LE encoding.

The error that the CLI would provide was a JSON formatting error.

Props goes to [Sudarpo Chong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093491/aws-s3api-json-formatting-error-error-parsing-parameter-cli-input-json-inval) with a comment on a similiar post, but doesn't focus on this as a key issue.

Summary:

- ensure **JSON file in UTF-8 encoding**.